# How to increase browserstack.idetimeout beyond 5mins, which has the maximum limit of 5 mins?

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, automated-tests, ui-automation, browserstack

Running selenium test in browstack, have an scenario where an backend datasetup runs more then 5mins, but the browserstack.idetimeout has maximum limit of 5 mins, how to increase the BS idle time limit?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum supported value for IDLE_TIMEOUT is 300 seconds (5 minutes). Should the need arise, you can add dummy commands such as fetching the page title which should reset the counter/timer after every command.

Something on the lines of:

```
Thread.sleep(30000);
driver.getTitle();
Thread.sleep(30000);
driver.getTitle();
Thread.sleep(30000);
driver.getTitle();
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, this solution doesn't help my scenario, the backend data setup runs for more then 300 secs and after that the test fails.